# What is the max password length for a Parse account

Tags: parse-platform

I am new to Parse and i was thinking about what might be the max length of characters permitted for a Parse Account's password?

Comment: So,if i create a user using PFUser the max length of the password character that,i can have my user to input is 30?

Comment: Don't limit the input. Just use the ParseUI stuff to create a login controller and let them worry about it.

Comment: Why are you asking us? Why don't you email them and ask? Why do you even care?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and Error: I created an Account with a passwort-length of more then 100.
It looks like it is unlimited.

Why does this matter to you?

---

@TZHX: I could use more then 30 characters

Comment: Unlimited? So 42 million billion is ok?

Comment: I just wanted to know whether Parse has any kind of max length like if you create an account in gmail then you have a restriction of 100 characters. Thank you!

Comment: @musefan: we all now infinity does not exist, don't we?

Comment: @Steve: if there is a special length of Passwort you want to achieve you will have to try it once. 100+ works anyway

Comment: @CodeiSir: Well how did Buzz Lightyear get there (and beyond) then if it doesn't exist? think before you speak will ya ;)

Comment: @musefan: I had to Google "Buzz Lightyear", what a nice joke, huhu :P

Answer (score 1):

On https://www.parse.com/signup, when making an account, there doesn't seem to be a limit. I just made a test account with a 90,000 character long password, and no errors were given.

[Edit: I tried a password of length 1,000,000 and the account was created successfully]